# Close menu onClick in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**My goal:** To close my Navbar when clicking on the button which is inside the Navbar.

I can't seem to get it to work - If anyone can explain to me what I'm doing wrong that would be great!

**Here's my Navbar:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Navbar() {
    const [showNav, setShowNav] = useState(true)


  return (
    <div isOpen={showNav} className="w-48 bg-gray-200 h-screen py-10">
        <button className="bg-primary w-32 h-12 rounded-lg text-white" onClick={() => setShowNav(false)}>Close Navbar</button>       
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        <h2>Menu item</h2>
        <h2>Menu item</h2>
        <h2>Menu item</h2>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Here is my App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="flex">
      <Navbar />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve what you need, you can also use the condition like this:

```html
return (
<>
  {showNav && <div className="w-48 bg-gray-200 h-screen py-10">
        <button className="bg-primary w-32 h-12 rounded-lg text-white" onClick={() => setShowNav(false)}>Close Navbar</button>       
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        <h2>Menu item</h2>
        <h2>Menu item</h2>
        <h2>Menu item</h2>
    </div>
   }
</>)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as `isOpen` property in div

## If you want to *hide* the element rather than not render it

set `display` to `none` in style if `showNav` is `false` Like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Navbar() {
    const [showNav, setShowNav] = useState(true)


  return (
    <div style={{display: showNav ? 'initial' : 'none'}} className="w-48 bg-gray-200 h-screen py-10">
        <button className="bg-primary w-32 h-12 rounded-lg text-white" onClick={() => setShowNav(false)}>Close Navbar</button>       
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        <h2>Menu item</h2>
        <h2>Menu item</h2>
        <h2>Menu item</h2>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Or use other way to hide an element (like `visibility` for example) see [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/hide-elements-in-css/) ways of hiding an element in CSS

## if you don’t wanna render it at all

Use [Snehasish Karmakar‘s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68861680/5923666)

Answer (score 0):

const [showNav, setShowNav] = useState(true)
change to
const [showNav, setShowNav] = useState("block");

onClick={() => setShowNav(false)}
change to
onClick={() => setShowNav("hidden")};

Comment: You shouldn’t do that, you are forcing it to use implementation detail (specific way of hiding an element)

Comment: actually yes. conditional loading is better. This was the closest to his question as hes looking to hide it with styling

Comment: I agree, but I meant don’t set the **state value** to implementation detail